# How can we handle the materials ____ ? We should let professionals ____ our children

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, causatives

We are not trained teachers. How can we handle the materials ____ ? We should let professionals
____ our children.

**My answer was:** to have taught / educate

**True Answer is:** to be taught / educate

Could you explain me why is my answer is wrong and why is the other one is correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The infinitive phrase **to have taught** refers to an action/process in the past.
The infinitive phrase **to be taught** refers to an action/process that lies in the future.

For example:

**To have taught the children so well must give you great satisfaction.** The teacher ought to be satisfied because s/he has taught the children well.

**To be taught, the children require essential text books.** In order to teach the children, essential text books will be required.

In your examples, the materials have not yet been taught to the children; they still need **to be taught**.